# Open Dialog IE Automation VBA

Tags: vba, excel, automation, internet-explorer-10, openfiledialog

I'm trying to log into a website and then upload some photos but I'm not getting any further. When the dialog opens, I can't control it programmatically. I tried to define an object as `FileDialog` and also to use the `Application.SendKeys` but it seems that the dialog isn't an application.

Comment: you should add your code to question

Comment: I believe you need to work on an internet Explorer object rather than a FileDialog. But please post some code, first.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a browser object with code similar to this:

.

```
Set browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

browser.Visible = True

brwser.navigate "http://stackoverflow.com/..." 'your address

Sleep 1000 'wait for 1 second

With browser.Document
   Set txtUsr = .getElementsByName("Username")
   Set txtPass = .getElementsByName("UserPass")
   Set btnLogin = .getElementById("btnLogin")
End With

txtUsr.innerText = "User Name"
txtPass.innerText = "Password"
btnLogin.Click
```

.

and so on...

- Use DOM, and try to avoid SendKeys if possible
- "Sleep" uses an API that can be declared at the top of the module like this:

  Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

.

**Edit**: I noticed that you are actually trying to interact with a dialog box, not a browser page. If so, you'll need to use Windows API functions to be able to first identify it from VBA; I'd suggest using "FindWindow":

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
 ByVal lpClassName As String, _
 ByVal lpWindowName As String _
) As Long
```

and call it from VBA like this:

```
setMyDialog = FindWindow(vbNullString, dialogCaption)
```

then send keys to it; you can send the "Tab" key to move from one text box to the next

If the website is using this dialog to allow you to select multiple images it will be more challenging to automate; you'll have to use other recordings methods to simulate multiple file selections or drag-and-drop actions with the mouse

Here are some links that can help with API functions:

- [How To Get a Window Handle Without Specifying an Exact Title](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/147659) (microsoft.com)
- [API Declarations for VB and VBA](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=12427) (microsoft.com)
- stackoverflow.com/questions/25098263/ (How to use FindWindow)

.

**Edit** for your 3 questions:

- "I get an error when i use the function. Something with the 64-bit system..." - you have a 64 bit version Excel so replace this declaration

.

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
     ByVal lpClassName As String, _
     ByVal lpWindowName As String _
) As Long
```

with this one:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
     ByVal lpClassName As String, _
     ByVal lpWindowName As String
) As LongPtr
```

.

- "When i copy the function VBA says that only comments may appear after End Sub..."

This is a declaration so it must be placed at the top of the module (before any other functions)

- What should I write instead of "vbNullString" and "dialogCaption"??

You can still use "vbNullString" as the first argument, but you have to replace "dialogCaption" with the title of your dialog box

- **do not use** quotation marks for vbNullString
- **do use** quotation marks for the title of the dialog

Comment: What should I write instead of "vbNullString" and "dialogCaption"??

Comment: I get an error when i use the function. Something with the 64-bit system that the code has to be updated

Comment: When i copy the function VBA says that only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function and End Property                                                            Where should I paste it?

Comment: Thank you all functioned but now when I try it out an error comes : "Object required" by findwindow before the app even starts

Comment: you may have to make the code wait until your dialog box pops up; you can use the "Sleep" API I mentioned earlier

Comment: Hello I used the sleep function but the debuger is giving me the same error as before. I have copied it before the findwindow. Is that right ?          Thank you 
Udar

Comment: ok. try to "step" through the code and identify which line is causing the error: place a breakpoint at the beginning of the function you call when it starts, then, pressing F8 will take through each line being executed, one by one. you'll need to investigate each element in the line that causes the error by holding the mouse over the variables in the lines to see their values when it runs. you can also add variables and statements to the "Watch" window to see the result of different operations. if you still have problems please provide the function causing the error

Comment: I've tried using a breakpoint but wherever I put the breakpoint the debuger is jumping over it and gives me the error with the object. Can you please give me your e-mail so I can send you my code? Best Regards Udar

Comment: sure, send it to me at dexxus at rogers dot com and I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Hello my code is like this :

```
1.I define an obj as internetexplorer.aplication
2.I login and then I want to upload a photo so I click the button for upload
' all works till now 
3.Now I try to interact with the dialog that let's me to choose the photos programmatically and their is my problem
```

Thank you Paul i'll try it today out!

Best Regards

Udar